# Eloquent - use unique string or unique int as id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

For my `users` table, Eloquent lets me use an `id` with `increment`:

```
$table->increments('id');
```

That is just fine. Every new user will get their `id`, 1, 2, 3, etc.

However the id should be an automatically assigned string or integer.

I want

- the user not to know how many users there are
- the user
  id to be *like* at least 5 digits (47533) or be a unique random string (f8hrcrft13)

How can I achieve this using Eloquent?

What I found so far:

```
$table->string('id', 36)->primary()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign ID while creating user model.

```
$data = [
    'id' => str_random(10),
    'first_name' => 'Andrej'
];

$user = User::create($data);
```

However, this will ignore ID you specify by default.
You need to edit `models/User.php` a bit and tell you do not want auto incrementing.
Add this property at the top

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Do not forget to change column type in users table from INT to VARCHAR.

Comment: Did you mean to set `$incrementing` to `true`?

Comment: Thanks. What is `str_random`? Cannot find it in PHP or Laravel. Own impl? Im looking for a built-in functionality to ensure my random id is unique.

Comment: `str_random` is Laravel helper function http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#strings You need to check on your own to see if ID is unique.

Answer (score 4):

dont change your database structure, incrementation of id is important to prevent error duplicate.

just using hashid **hashid.org**

> **Generate short hashes from numbers (like YouTube and Bitly).**
>
> obfuscate database IDs · use them as forgotten password hashes · invitation codes · store shard numbers

```
$hashids = new Hashids\Hashids('this is my salt');
$hash = $hashids->encrypt(1, 2, 3);
$numbers = $hashids->decrypt($hash);

var_dump($hash, $numbers);
```

return :

```
string(5) "laUqtq"

array(3) {
   [0]=>
   int(1)
   [1]=>
   int(2)
   [2]=>
   int(3)
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at hasids. So would you use the incrementing id and an additional userid generated with hashids?

Answer (score 2):

Make a slug for each user with its username e.g.

```
example.org/user/john
```

Then if there are two users with *john* username append a counter to differentiate them.

```
example.org/user/john-1
```

Endusers won't see any id. This is a much cleaner way than assigning a random number to each User alias.

You can do this easily with https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable